# Возвращает null при выводе параметров объекта в консоль

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста!  Надо прочитать файл с логами, сделать из них объект (для дальнейшего сравнения параметров и вывода по параметрам в консоль), вывести параметры объекта в консоль. У меня выводит NULL по всем параметрам.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class LogsFromFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String contents = getTextFromFile("D:\\QA Automation\\practice\\practice files\\Logs\\transactions.log_04-02-18-07_01");
        //System.out.println(contents);

        for (String logs : severalLogs(contents)) {
            //System.out.println(logs.substring(0,7));
            Log log = new Log(logs.substring(1, 6), logs.substring(8, 15),
                    logs.substring(logs.indexOf("transaction") + 13));
            //System.out.println(log);
            System.out.print("день "  + log.logText + " / " + "время " + log.time + " / " + " текст " + log.logText);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public static String getTextFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    }

    public static String[] severalLogs(String text) {
        return text.split("\\n");
    }
}


class Log {
    String day;
    String time;
    String logText;

    Log(String d, String t, String log) {
        d = day;
        t = time;
        log = logText;
    }
}
```

Comment: `day = d` и так далее

Comment: большое спасибо